# Django - Determining how to split into apps based on functionality

Tags: python, django

Completely new to Django. I'm building a website where users can make profiles, search for other profiles, and view basic information.

I'm unsure about how to organize the apps. I want to following things on the navigation bar:
"About Us", "How it Works", "Join", "Login"

I know that users (join + login) will be its own app, but how would I bundle all of the information that will show up on the navigation bar? Will that just be one main app because it doesn't really do anything complex and really just presents text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of app in Django is that it does thing. For example if you are creating a website for school you have students as an app which manages students, an app for exams which only manages exams, grades etc. So your app should typically do one thing, if it does not break it down. The whole idea behind Django is having modular components which can act on their own.

In your case, what I would do is create an app called userapp. In userapp, I will have profile as a model containing username, password, fname, lname, picture, dob, hobbies etc.

On your home page, you can have separate flatpages for about us, how it works. These do not have to be app.

My project structure

```
├───.idea
├───firstapp
│   ├───migrations
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   └───__pycache__
├───myproj
│   └───__pycache__
├───secondapp
│   ├───migrations
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   └───__pycache__
├───static
│   ├───admin
│   │   ├───css
│   │   ├───fonts
│   │   ├───img
│   │   │   └───gis
│   │   └───js
│   │       ├───admin
│   │       └───vendor
│   │           ├───jquery
│   │           └───xregexp
│   ├───css
│   ├───fonts
│   ├───img
│   └───js
└───templates
    └───firstapp
```

Comment: Would your homepage be an app? I started the project and I have my main directory "website" which has __init__, settings, wsgi,and urls. Do I need to make an app called homepage in order to handle the <domainname>.com URL?

Comment: No sir. Your home page is not an app. I mean you make it but homepage is generally where you put up all the apps. I have updated my answer with my project structure to give you an idea.